# How to remove similarity string between two strings in php

Tags: php, string, similarity

I have two strings like this:

```
$str_1 = 'catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
$str_2 = 'catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

How can I remove '**catalog/view/javascript/**' from **$str_2**.

Thank you!

Comment: you can use `explode("/",$str);`  then you use `unset `or any remove method

Comment: I did do it. But I want to know some shorter code like XOR operator to get the similarity string or I remove all string is same in two variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$str_2 = 'catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
echo str_replace( "catalog/view/javascript/", "", $str_2 );
```

Comment: I think he wants to determine what should be removed from `$str_1`.

Comment: Possible but that is not what he has written in the question.  He has asked how to remove part of the string.  If the OP wants a comparison then I am sure something else can be written.

Answer (score 0):

[demo here](https://eval.in/670366)

```
<?php
$str_1 = 'catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
$str_2 = 'catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
$length = strlen($str_1);
$index = 0;
while($index < $length)
{
    if(strpos($str_2, substr($str_1, 0, $index + 1)) === false)
        break;
    $index++;
}
$str_2 =  substr($str_2, $index);
echo $str_2;
```

Comment: It seems interesting but I need some shorter code. Thankyou!

Comment: @Diego I thought you were remove the same part with str_1 from str_2. It seems you don't want that, $str_1 misleads me?????.     $str_2 = 'catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
echo $str_2 = substr($str_2, strlen('catalog/view/javascript/')); works for you.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry if I make you sad. I mean, your code is working, but I want to some shorter code like XOR operator, maybe!

Ex: while($str_1[$i] ^ $str_2[$i]) { $i++} ....